# Access Class Member in XAML Code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

How to preform the following result in a my WPF project.

C# Code Behind

```
public class Test
{
    public int a;
}
```

Custom Control Code Behind

```
public class myControl : Control
{
    public Test myVar { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml Code

```
<myControl myVar.a=2/>
```

For Example, Using this Code like TextBlock Class in under code:

```
<TextBox TextBlock.FontFamily="12"/>
```

Comment: You might be looking for dependency property https://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

Answer (score 0):

The example you give with TextBlock

```
<TextBox TextBlock.FontFamily="12"/>
```

is a different case, because TextBlock is not a property of TextBox.

Here you are setting a so called attached property.

Following your example, you would have to write the Test class as follows:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
  public class Test
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty aProperty
      = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ( "a",
                                              typeof(int),
                                              typeof(Test),
                                              new PropertyMetadata(0) ) ;

    public static int Geta ( DependencyObject obj )
    {
      return (int)obj.GetValue(aProperty);
    }

    public static void Seta ( DependencyObject obj, int value )
    {
      obj.SetValue(aProperty, value);
    }
  }
}
```

You can then set it in XAML as follows:

```
<local:myControl local:Test.a="2" />
```

Note that I am not using your property myVar at all.

If this is what you want, I suggest you do some background reading on attached properties.